# make a timer count down and score displayed on the screen in Cocos2D

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

How can I apply a timer count down in Cocos2D and the score counter that both will be display on the screen?

I am still new to this

Please help me out

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look into the [Timer](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_timer.html) class. Here is a [link to the Timer class overview - cocos2d for iPhone 0.8.2](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_timer.html). You won't need to implement one directly (but indirectly), but its good to know how it works.

For displaying the actual counter in the screen using cocos2d, have a look at [LabelAtlas](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_label_atlas.html). Here is a [link to LabelAtlas class overview - cocos2d for iPhone 0.8.2](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/api-ref/latest-stable/interface_label_atlas.html)

```
/* basically you create a LabelAtlas subclass that
   has a method for updating itself with the current time
   or score. I will call it ScoreLabel in this example */
ScoreLabel * bonusScore = [[ScoreLabel alloc] initWithString:@"0"
                                              charMapFile:@"charMap.png"
                                              itemWidth:10
                                              itemHeight:10
                                              startCharMap:'0'];
// then schedule a method to be called that updates the current score
// schedule: paramter of type SEL. It should pass the method to be scheduled
// interval is in seconds, it determines how often the method is called.
[bonusScore schedule:@selector(updateScore) interval:0.5];

/* the implementation of the updateScore method could be */
-(void)updateScore {
    [self setString: [[World sharedWorld] timeLeft]]];
}
```

Have a look at the cocos2d examples for AtlasSprites (and for LabelAtlas) to see how to implement the image you need to support the class.